# Adobe reader shows just one document (pdf) at a time

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

Adobe shows just one document (pdf) at a time and close all opened when i close one, how can i see two windows simultaneously, and close just one document?

Comment: Which version and on what platform?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by choosing `Cascade` from the `Window` menu item. Or with the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>`+`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>J</kbd>.

[image: Window > Cascade]

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you might uncheck the "Open cross-document links in same window" option in the Documents tab of the Preferences.